# change size and maxlength allowed for a field in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

How can I change the size and max allowed characters for a field using Simple Forms.  I've tried following but does not work:

```
<%= f.input :lastname, :size => 40, :max => 4 %>
```

I know there is a `default_input_size` in `initializers/simple_form.rb` however, I don't want to change the size globally but just on few fields.

How would I do this?

Comment: What is so good about simple form?..This would be like `f.text_filed :last_name, :size => 40, :maxlength => 4` in normal Rails. More easier?!

Comment: @rubyprince simpleform `f.input` also takes care of the (translated) label and other nice features that you'd otherwise have to implement manually.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
<%= f.input :lastname, input_html: { maxlength: 15, size: 40} %>
```

Comment: also I would prefer the "new" syntax

`= f.input :lastname, input_html: {maxlength: 15, size: 100}`

(in haml)

Answer (score 6):

try to use `<%= f.input :lastname, :input_html => {:size => 40, :maxlength => 4} %>`

Comment: This answer is now a dup, although more correct as it copies the values from the OP.

Answer (score 5):

Or try to use CSS `<%= f.input :lastname, :input_html => {:style => 'width: 250px'} %>`

Answer (score 2):

Adding size and maxlength in input_html had no effect for me.
I am using "input_field" instead of "input".
So the following worked:

```
<%= form.input_field :effective_from_date,
                     as: :string,
                     class: 'activate-datepicker',
                     maxlength: 11,
                     size: 11,
                     label: false %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you declared your css for input widths set to 'auto'. Remove that declaration, and then customize.