# Rails Simple Form Max Length for Multi Value Input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, maxlength

I am trying to limit birth_year input's value to 4 in my form.However this piece of code does not work. birth_year is not an attribute, so I can not validate in my model. Is there a way to limit it to 4 ?

```
<%= f.input :birth_year, as: :multi_value, label: false, hint: t("simple_form.labels.person.birth_year"), input_html: { maxlength: "4"} %>
```

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change size and maxlength allowed for a field in simple\_form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342477/change-size-and-maxlength-allowed-for-a-field-in-simple-form)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I guess its because I am using multi valued input.Thanks anyway.